# How to create listener for GtkToolItem in toolbar?

Tags: c, gtk2

I created GTK application coded with `C`.

I added tool bar:

[image]

here is relevant snippets of code:

```
GtkWidget *toolbar;
GtkToolItem *new;
GtkToolItem *open;
GtkToolItem *save;
GtkToolItem *sep;
GtkToolItem *exit;





...
toolbar = gtk_toolbar_new();    
gtk_toolbar_set_style(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS);

gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(toolbar), 2);

new = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_NEW);
gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), new, -1);

open = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_OPEN);
gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), open, -1);

save = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_SAVE);
gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), save, -1);

sep = gtk_separator_tool_item_new();
gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), sep, -1); 

exit = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_QUIT);
gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), exit, -1); 


....



gtk_widget_show_all (window);
```

The question is, how to add listeners (callbacks) to tool bar when I press on quit/open...

For single button I have something like:

```
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_button_clicked), NULL);

void on_button_clicked(){...}
```

I know the way to do it through `gtk_ui_manager` but it too complicated.

Please, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on main window?

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(exit), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
```

More info: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/menusandtoolbars/